# How to find matches in numpy arrays automatically in a for loop in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop

I wat to search for indices of an array in two other arrays and want to find out where they match. Firstly, I have a variable which says how many points will be matched It is called `brk`. This `brk` equals the length of my search array (`searched`). In my simple case `brk = 2` which means I will have 4 match points (`brk * 2`). So, I must split my search arry into `brk` halves and then search each half in each main array (`main_x_arr` and `main_y_arr`). I have always one search array and two main arrays, but `brk` changes and says ho to search for indices. At the moment I am creating each match manually but I am trying to create matches auromatically. This is my code:

```
searched=np.array([[1., 2.], [-3., 1.]])
brk=len(searched)
main_y_arr=np.array([[1., 5.], [8., 3.], [-3., 8.], [2., 4.]])
main_x_arr=np.array([[1., 7.], [-3., 1.], [4., 7.], [2., 4.]])
match1= np.min (np.unique (np.where((main_y_arr==searched[:int (len(searched)/2)].reshape (-1,1)[:,None]).any(-1))[1]))
match2= np.max (np.unique (np.where((main_x_arr==searched[:int (len(searched)/2):].reshape (-1,1)[:,None]).any(-1))[1]))
match3= np.min (np.unique (np.where((main_y_arr==searched[int (len(searched)/2):].reshape (-1,1)[:,None]).any(-1))[1]))
match4= np.max (np.unique (np.where((main_x_arr==searched[int (len(searched)/2):].reshape (-1,1)[:,None]).any(-1))[1]))
```

As it can be seen, I am creating each match but I want to find a way to firstly kno I will have `2 * brk` matches. Then, split `searched` array into the number of `brk` and after that search for each split in each array which makes `4` matches. If the length of my `searched` array equals `3`, then I will have thre splits and finall `6` (eactly like repeating `match1` and `match2` for three slices to make 6 matches). Or if it is `1`, I will have only `2` matches (exactly like having `match1` and `match2` for only one single slide) because it cannot be splitted anymore.
In advance I do appreciate any help and feedback.

Comment: can you describe what you are trying to accomplish in a sentence ? 
I'm mostly guessing here: (something like) I have a list of (x,y)-points [seached] i want to search for in a list of points [main] ...

Comment: Dear @lwohlhart, Thanks for devoting time to me. in a sentence: finding the indices of `searched` in my main arrays. But the point is that it is not always simple. Sometimes I need to split `searched` rray and look for each split separately and find the mathed index.

Comment: okay, do i understand it correctly that main_x_arr and main_y_arr  together define the x and y coordinates of your *main*-points?  
So there's are the  points [(1,1), (7,5), (-3,8),(1,3), .......] ? 
If so then I think your life would be easier if you reorganize the declaration of your main points array ( even if it's just for the search )

Comment: @lwohlhart, unfortunately they are not x and y coordinates of the points. They are just some numbers. In fact, they are numbers of some points in x and y directions and I want to find the matches between these numbers and numbers stored in `searched` array.

Comment: nah sorry, now that I read the declaration of your points again; my interpretation doesn't really make sense

Comment: okay i think we're coming close: the actual question at hand is :
can you formulate what makes a *match* ( mathematically or in words )

Comment: Yes, I have written the matches. You do not need the mathematical complexity. Just I want to use `np.where` function. My first and second matches can be repeated for as many as matches I have. Just I need and exception which is for the cases where I have only one match: I just `match1` and `match2` but o not split the `searched` which has only one row.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229767/discussion-between-lwohlhart-and-ali-d).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after a lengthy discussion we decided that this solves the OPs requirements:

```
matches = []
for current_search in searched:
    current_search_reshaped = current_search.reshape(-1,1,1)
    match_min = np.min(np.unique(np.where((main_y_arr == current_search_reshaped).any(-1))[1]))
    match_max = np.max(np.unique(np.where((main_x_arr == current_search_reshaped).any(-1))[1]))
    matches.append((match_min, match_max))
```